# Visual Studio Typescript min file output when publishing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, typescript

in my project i have several ts files, those when transpiled generates the correct output and generates a .js, min.js and min.js.map. All of them are transpiled on save and files are updated automatically, but they are not under source control and don't belong to the visual studio project solution, i'm ok with that.

Then in my mvc bundle configuration y create a bundle that takes everything in one folder and creates my bundle, thats fine, and if i set `EnableOptimizations = true`, then my bundle is  served and minified, no problems at all. I create my budle this way

```
  var appBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app");
  appBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/ScriptsApp", "*.js", true);
  appBundle.Transforms.Add(jsTransformer);
  appBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
  bundles.Add(appBundle);
```

During devlopement works fine because if i'm wright `IncludeDirectory` will search in my folder instead of my project.

But when i publish my web application in the output are placed only the .js files not the .min.js, thats why then my bundle works but it's not minified because the min.js files are not present.

I know that this may be not the best approach in order to build a bundle, but it is the approach taken and i can't change if.

**My question is, how can i change my building configuration in order to place those .min.js on the output?**

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? You could use Gulp or Grunt to achieve this. If you still have problems let me know.

Comment: Yes i know that this task is more suitable for Gulp or Grunt, finnaly i used gulp. But for this project i left as it is and just bundle the js without minfying. Thanks anyway